# Delete selected files from Basecamp using API or any Script

Tags: php, api, basecamp

I don't seem to find a way to delete files from Basecamp using their API. I was able to get the file details though.

I am trying to achieve the below:

1. Get the files of user after authentication - Achieved
2. Select the files we want to delete
3. Delete them

Is this possible. Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this `DELETE /projects/1/documents/1.json`

Docs: https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/documents.md#delete-document